# using ++ in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Just a quick one. I need a simple animation that basically says.

`$("#rightArrow").hover(function() {
        $('.projectImages').css('left', '++27px');
    });`

I've tested it and it seems that the ++ is the wrong syntax here. Just wondering what it was that was supposed to go in. I've tried += and I've also tried using the animation feature but the closest I've got so far is this

```
$("#rightArrow").hover(function() {
    $('.projectImages').animate({left: '+=27px'}, 'slow');
});
```

Which gives some interesting results but not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: css attributes never accept mathematical operations

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? If neither example gives you what you are looking for then they can't serve as examples for us to help you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I thought I'd mentioned it. 

I wanted a div to scroll continously when the "rightArrow" was hovered over.

Comment: @Vivek: indeed, but `jQuery.animate` will interpret this syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/fqedE/) with a continuously sliding object by starting/clearing an interval function:

```
timer=null;

$("#rightArrow").hover(function(e) {
    timer=setInterval( function(){
      var left = $("#x").position().left;
      $("#x").animate({
          left: ""+(left+100)+"px"
      });
    });
    //alert($("#x").position().left);
}, 
function(e){ // exit function
    clearInterval( timer );
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a quick and easy way to do it, due to how Javascript handles strings and integers. Try:

```
$("#rightArrow").hover(function() {
    newLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'), 10) + 27;
    $('.projectImages').animate({left: newLeft + 'px'}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: @Sam: Then your method might be wrong - I was simply looking at the ++27px part.

Answer (score -1):

in Javascript if you are using eval() you are probably doing something wrong. Use 
parseInt() instead.

Comment: I haven't used eval() anywhere :S

Comment: One of the examples above did